# PowerBI. Проблемы с кодировкой заголовка при импорте из MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка, powerbi

При импорте данных в PowerBI из базы MySQL заголовки столбцов вместо кириллицы отображаются кракозябрами. При этом сами значения отображаются корректно кириллицей. Как это можно пофиксить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

СHARSETS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заголовки столбцов берутся из полученного rowset? тогда смотри на результат `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` и datebase/table/column charset.

Comment: Не помогло. Кодировка в базе стоит utf8_general_ci. Заголовок формируется не из самого датасета, а тянется с заголовка таблицы в самом MySQL.

Comment: *Кодировка в базе стоит utf8_general_ci*. Это какая именно из многочисленных кодировок? добавьте в вопрос ВСЕ их. *Заголовок формируется не из самого датасета, а тянется с заголовка таблицы в самом MySQL.* Я и говорю про структуру.

Comment: Пробовал ставить SET NAMES 'utf8' - не помогло.

Comment: А по каким соображениям character_set_server сделан latin1?

Comment: Сервер не я админю, поэтому затрудняюсь ответить. Разве это не дефолтное значение?
Я пробовал предварительно менять его на SET SESSION character_set_server='utf8' также безрезультатно.

Comment: А при чём тут дефолтное значение? Настраиваться-то надо как тебе требуется. Сам же видишь, что имена полей тебе падают в utf8, а клиент их рисует в чём-то типа ANSI. Так что единственное решение - заставить клиента правильно понимать и отображать кодировку имён полей. Кстати, а зачем вообще потребовалось использовать нестандартные символы в именах объектов?

Comment: Я пробовал менять все кроме system/filesystem как на utf8, так и на cp1251 - в MySQL все отображается в кириллице, на выходе заголовки некорректные. Прогнал эти кракозябры через онлайн декодер, он показал, что исходная кодировка 1252.

Comment: Проблема решилась добавлением Encoding=TextEncoding.UTF8 в запрос PowerQuery